# Installing GCC Make on Windows 7 x64

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I installed GNAT 2012 a while back when I was working with Ada and it came with a version of GCC. I can compile C files from the command prompt using gcc fine, but "make" apparently wasn't included.

How would I go about getting make working? Should I just install the newest version of GCC instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make is not part of GCC. On Windows, you can use [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS). It includes make and other useful tools.